# Set the attached property the items in the ItemsControl using my custom panel does not work in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've created a custom panel with which you can do the following:

```
<custom:Timeline>
    <Button custom:Timeline.PointInTime="6:30 PM" />
</custom:Timeline>
```

When I do this, it works wonderfully.  However, when I do something like this (which is what I need to do):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TimelineItemTemplate">
    <Grid d:DesignWidth="169" custom:Timeline.PointInTime="{Binding NotifyTime}">

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TimelineItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <custom:Timeline/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

the PointInTime attached property is not set on the controls in the `InternalChildren` collection:

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size a_arrangeBounds)
{
    foreach (UIElement uiChild in InternalChildren)
    {
        var pointInTime = GetPointInTime(uiChild);

        // Arranginess stuff
        // Timeline.PointInTimeProperty is not set on 'uiChild'. WTH?
    }

    return base.ArrangeOverride(a_arrangeBounds);
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't post the answer into the question; also, the `Y U NO` may be cute, but it doesn't belong here. If you want to post an answer, you can do so, but your best bet is to edit the working answer code into the accepted answer.

Comment: Its fine if you want to edit my posted question from a year ago, but when you comment about it, its a bit condescending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ItemTemplates` are inside a container, for `ItemsControls` that container is a `ContentPresenter`. In any case you probably want to bind the property in the `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` which will set the property on the container.

Comment: I don't want to set the property on the container, I want to set the property on the control in the container.  It works similar to `Grid.Row`.  Each item in the `ItemsControl` will have a different value set for `PointInTime`.  If this is what you mean, please demonstrate with some code.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Jordan: You do want to set it on the container, because that is what is added to your panel (with a Grid it's the same thing, if you set t in the data template the Grid won't see it). Also adding a setter to a style shoulf not require my assistance.

Comment: Oh, ITEM container.  I see.  So its what each item gets wrapped in.  I should just put a ContentPresenter in there and attach PointInTime to it?

Comment: This begs the question, how do I bind to an attached property on a style?

Comment: @Jordan: `<Setter Property="custom:Timeline.PointInTime" Value="..."/>` as i said, it's trivial...

Comment: Ah, trivial but not elementary. It worked.  Thanks.  Hey speaking of trivial, did you catch the "Y U NO".  I am so cool _*sarcasm*.